# Test OSX app under scarce system resources

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa, xcode-instruments

I noticed that my app crashes more often for users with slower machines (like MacBook Air or MacBook Pro with CPU lower than i5). However, as a developer, it's hard for me to reproduce these problems on my machine (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013, 2.7 GHz Core i7 16GB RAM).

The app is CPU intensive (real-time multi-peer audio-video conferencing) and multithreaded and most crashes occur accidentally during key operations like start/stop audio or video streaming/capturing - sure sign of bad multi-threading interoperation.

Thus, I was wondering, are there any tools for testing application under scarce system resources (like limiting cores or CPU frequency/execution time for the app process) which will help me understand system requirements and limits of my app as well as help to reproduce certain [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)?

Answer (score 1):

In the Apple Developers Resources there is the **Hardware IO Tools for Xcode**, that contains the **Network Link Conditioner Tool**, very useful to test your projects under critical Network condition.

Thus, it only allows you to simulate scarce networking resources, not system's: so I can suggest you to create a **Virtual Machine** and run Xcode or your IDE from there, and you previously decide how many resources (cpu cores, graphical memory, RAM) allocate.